# How does one denote the number of elements of a set $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have a specific set of some elements like:

$$X = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

How can one make an expression for the number of elements of the set $X$?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for the [cardinality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of a set, which is usually denoted by vertical bars:

$$| X |$$

Answer (score 13):

It's common enough to write $\#X$, too.

Answer (score 3):

It is commonly denoted with vertical or double vertical lines: $|X|$ or $||X||$. Once I also saw an accent: $\bar{X}$.

Comment: Never saw the double vars (rather used form norms in  Banach spaces) One also finds $\sharp X$.

Comment: I think it is $\#X$ rather than $\sharp X$.

Answer (score 3):

I have aso seen $n(X)$ (in Herstein I believe).

Comment: This isn't uncommon in lower-level math courses. The Finite Math book I am teaching out of right now uses it.